# .ccf CommView File Format

Tags: file

I need to do a small application able to dump the contents of a CommView .ccf file.

Does anyone know the format of this file type?

Is the content mangled or encrypted?

Any help will be usefull :D

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Take a look at this](http://aluigi.altervista.org/papers/ncf2cap.zip), it's a converter from NCF or CCF files to the CAP format used by Wireshark.  The source is included with the executable, so that should give you an insight on how the format is structured.